# Finding bijection between sets of increasing and non-decreasing sequences of equal lenght

Tags: combinatorics

> Give a bijection from the set of strictly increasing sequences of integers from $\{1, \dots, m + d - 1\}$ with length $m$ to the set of non-decreasing sequences of integers from $\{1, \dots, d\}$ also with length m.

I'm sure there is a simple way of looking at this but I have not been able think of a suitable bijection. Clearly, all strictly increasing sequences of integers from $\{1, \dots, d\}$ are mapped to themselves in the set of non-decreasing integers from $\{1, \dots, d\}$. But where are the sequences containing an integer greater than $d$ mapped to? I considered mapping the remaining strictly increasing sequences to those non-decreasing sequences with the most common integers, but this seems like a long shot.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint. Can you solve the problem when $m=2$? Think about gaps.

Comment: Thank you for your response @EthanBolker